# Probleme with my first project: Chrome Extension. I am stuck

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have recently created a beginner's Chrome extension project. The idea behind this project is to simulate an automatic click on the "F1" key and display a confirmation message when I click the extension's execution button.

The issue is that everything seems to be set up correctly, but when I click on the extension's button, the intended action doesn't occur.

- The extension is correctly activated.
- All other extensions are disabled.
- The popup window (popup) displays correctly when I click on the extension
  icon in the Chrome toolbar.
- The Chrome development console does not show any errors.
- Chrome is updated

My manifest.json file code is here

```
   {
     "manifest_version": 3,
     "name": "F1 AutoPress Extension",
     "version": "1.0",
     "description": "Automatically press the F1 key",
     "permissions": ["activeTab"],
     "action": {
       "default_popup": "popup.html",
       "default_icon": {
         "16": "images/icon16.png",
         "48": "images/icon48.png",
         "128": "images/icon128.png"
       }
     },
     "background": {
       "service_worker": "background.js"
     },
     "icons": {
       "16": "images/icon16.png",
       "48": "images/icon48.png",
       "128": "images/icon128.png"
     }
   }
```

My popup.js file code is here:

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     document.getElementById("pressF1Button").addEventListener("click", function() {
       chrome.scripting.executeScript({
         target: { tabId: -1 }, // Modify the target tab ID if needed
         function: function() {
           document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "F1" }));
           document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", { key: "F1" }));
            alert("Button clicked"); // Show an alert
         }
       });
     });
   });
```

My popup.html file code is here

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>F1 AutoPress Extension</title>
     <script src="popup.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <button id="pressF1Button">Press F1</button>
   </body>
   </html>
```

My background.js file is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you may want to format your code on multiple lines (by prepending each with four spaces) so we can read your code better, and change your title to let us have a preview of your issue. Try adding some debug in your extension so see if your DOMContentLoaded runs at all, and then narrow down the problem to something like "function ... doesn't run", or "returns this error".

Comment: Half of your code is commented out because it's in one line after `//`. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.